# Is there a simple fix to get my launcher size slider bar back in Settings>Appearance?

Tags: launcher, icons, resize

My launcher icon size slider bar recently disappeared from the system settings since recent updates.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, but I am not comfortable editing files or anything like that, so I need a simple fix.  Thanks!

Comment: 12.04 has two graphical shells, Unity and Unity-2d. The former has the Launcher resize slider, the latter does not. Logout, click on the cog wheel next to the user name field, select Unity as session, and log back in. Is "your slider" back?

Answer (score 0):

**CompizConfig Settings Manager** (**ccsm** from Terminal)

[image]

and change icons size:

[image]